# Unable to run application as a root user in centos6.5

Tags: linux, centos6, bitnami, openerp-7

I am working on centos6.5 server. I have logged in as a root user. I am trying to run Openerp 7 which is a bitnami version. When I am running the application like this

```
opt/openerp-7.0-12/apps/openerp/scripts/./openerp_no_multi_process.sh start
```

it prompted me for password and I have entered the same root password. then it showed

```
[root@kstest /]# opt/openerp-7.0-12/apps/openerp/scripts/./openerp_no_multi_process.sh start
Password:
su: incorrect password
opt/openerp-7.0-12/apps/openerp/scripts/./openerp_no_multi_process.sh : openerp_no_multi_process could not be started
```

I was able to run other applications postgresql and apache, they prompted me for password I entered the root password and there are no issues.
for conformation I have checked in the openerp-server.conf file which is in the path vi opt/openerp-7.0-12/apps/openerp/conf/openerp-server.conf

```
[options]
addons_path = /opt/openerp-7.0-12/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20130922_231028-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons
admin_passwd = abcxyz
csv_internal_sep = ,
db_host = 127.0.0.1
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = bitnami_openerp
db_password = abcxyz
db_port = 5432
```

abcxyz is the root password.
Can anyone please tell what can be the issue ? why am i not able to start the service.?

I am editing it.
As there is no user openerp in my server. I have created a new user openerp.

```
adduser openerp
```

then  I tried to change the password.
    passwd openerp
I cam up with this.

```
[root@kstest /]# passwd openerp
passwd: system_u:system_r:virtd_lxc_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 is not authorized to change the password of openerp
```

Comment: you need to use 'openerp' username; try 'sudo su - openerp' in a terminal...

Comment: http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/ this is one version down but gives info on how to install - possibly worth you following this

Comment: I have already installed it and it was up and running a day back. Today when i was running it I came up that my openerp service is not running and I came up with this error "openerp_no_multi_process could not be started" postgres and apache are still running.

Comment: You're trying to run this inside a Linux container, and not in a regular virtual machine or physical machine. Either run it in a VM or update the container host to CentOS 7 where this should be possible in a container.